# WooCommerce checkout Order Review Table variation Display none

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am using a multi-step form with over 50 input fields.
While doing checkout, the product purchased with the title shows up along with the loads of those variations as long list. I want to set the css display property of those variations set to none. But i am not able to succeed. Followed is the html code outputted

---

```
<div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
        <table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name">Product</th>
            <th class="product-total">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                            <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            888 Business Innovation &amp; Investment - Permanent&nbsp;                           <strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>                          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-Title">Title::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Title"><p>Mr</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-FamilyName">Family Name::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-FamilyName"><p>jaganathan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-GivenName">Given Name::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-GivenName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Address">Address::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Address"><p>Fl.No#13, Raja Apartments, 5/15 Balakris<br>Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600033<br>India<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Fl.No%2313%2C+Raja+Apartments%2C+5%2F15+Balakris+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600033+India" target="_blank" class="map-it-link">Map It</a></p>
</dd>

        <dd class="variation-Currentcountryofresidence"><p>India</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Citizenshipasshownonpassport">Citizenship as shown on passport?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Citizenshipasshownonpassport"><p>indian</p>
</dd>

        <dd class="variation-Haveyouoranyofyourfamilymembersbeenconvictedofanycriminaloffences"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Doyouoranyofyourfamilymembershaveanyknownhealthproblems">Do you or any of your family members have any known health problems?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Doyouoranyofyourfamilymembershaveanyknownhealthproblems"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-IcurrentlyholdaBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188andwouldliketobeassessedfortheBusinessInnovationandInvestmentPermanentvisasubclass888">I currently hold a Business Innovation and Investment (Provisional) visa (subclass 188) and would like to be assessed for the Business Innovation and Investment (Permanent) visa (subclass 888):</dt>
        <dd class="variation-IcurrentlyholdaBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188andwouldliketobeassessedfortheBusinessInnovationandInvestmentPermanentvisasubclass888"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-HaveyouandyourpartnercompliedwithCommonwealthStateorTerritorylawsforthebusinessyouoperateandemployeesinthebusiness">Have you and your partner complied with Commonwealth, State or Territory laws for the business you operate and employees in the business.:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-HaveyouandyourpartnercompliedwithCommonwealthStateorTerritorylawsforthebusinessyouoperateandemployeesinthebusiness"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YouhavenooutstandingdebtstotheAustralianGovernmentorhavearrangedtorepayanyoutstandingdebtstotheAustralianGovernment">You have no outstanding debts to the Australian Government or have arranged to repay any outstanding debts to the Australian Government.:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YouhavenooutstandingdebtstotheAustralianGovernmentorhavearrangedtorepayanyoutstandingdebtstotheAustralianGovernment"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-UnderwhichstreamwasyourBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalVisaSubclass188granted">Under which stream was your Business Innovation and Investment (Provisional) Visa (Subclass 188) granted::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-UnderwhichstreamwasyourBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalVisaSubclass188granted"><p>Investor</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-HaveyoubeeninAustraliaandheldaBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188intheBusinessInnovationstreamortheBusinessInnovationExtensionstreamoraSpecialCategoryvisasubclass444foratleastoneyear">Have you been in Australia and held a Business Innovation and Investment (Provisional) visa (subclass 188) in the Business Innovation stream or the Business Innovation Extension stream or a Special Category visa (subclass 444) for at least one year?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-HaveyoubeeninAustraliaandheldaBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188intheBusinessInnovationstreamortheBusinessInnovationExtensionstreamoraSpecialCategoryvisasubclass444foratleastoneyear"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-ForthepasttwoyearsIhaveownedandactivelyoperatedamainbusinessinAustralia">For the past two years I have owned and actively operated a main business in Australia::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-ForthepasttwoyearsIhaveownedandactivelyoperatedamainbusinessinAustralia"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-HadanannualturnoverofatleastAUD300000fromthemainbusinessorbusinessesinthelast12months">Had an annual turnover of at least AUD300 000 from the main business (or businesses) in the last 12 months::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-HadanannualturnoverofatleastAUD300000fromthemainbusinessorbusinessesinthelast12months"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-OwnedatleastoneofthefollowingpercentagesofthemainbusinessormainbusinessesinAustraliainthelastyear">Owned at least one of the following percentages of the main business (or main businesses) in Australia in the last year::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-OwnedatleastoneofthefollowingpercentagesofthemainbusinessormainbusinessesinAustraliainthelastyear"><p>C.    10 per cent of a publicly listed company</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-HaveanAustralianBusinessNumberABNforeachofyourmainbusinesses">Have an Australian Business Number (ABN) for each of your main businesses::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-HaveanAustralianBusinessNumberABNforeachofyourmainbusinesses"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-SubmittedBusinessActivityStatementstotheAustralianTaxationOfficeforthelasttwoyears">Submitted Business Activity Statements to the Australian Taxation Office for the last two years::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-SubmittedBusinessActivityStatementstotheAustralianTaxationOfficeforthelasttwoyears"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-NetvalueofbusinessassetsofatleastAUD200000inyournominatedmainbusinessortwomainbusinessesinAustraliathroughouttheyear">Net value of business assets of at least AUD200 000 in your nominated main business (or two main businesses) in Australia throughout the year::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-NetvalueofbusinessassetsofatleastAUD200000inyournominatedmainbusinessortwomainbusinessesinAustraliathroughouttheyear"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-NetvalueofpersonalandbusinessassetsofatleastAUD600000inAustraliathroughouttheyear">Net value of personal and business assets of at least AUD 600,000 in Australia throughout the year::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-NetvalueofpersonalandbusinessassetsofatleastAUD600000inAustraliathroughouttheyear"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Employedatleasttheequivalentoftwofull-timeemployeesinyourmainbusinessormainbusinessesthroughouttheyearimmediatelybeforeyouapplywhoareAustraliancitizensAustralianpermanentresidentsorholdersofvalidNewZealandpassportsandnotmembersofyourfamily">Employed at least the equivalent of two full-time employees in your main business (or main businesses), throughout the year immediately before you apply who are:   Australian citizens, Australian permanent residents, or holders of valid New Zealand passports and not members of your family.:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Employedatleasttheequivalentoftwofull-timeemployeesinyourmainbusinessormainbusinessesthroughouttheyearimmediatelybeforeyouapplywhoareAustraliancitizensAustralianpermanentresidentsorholdersofvalidNewZealandpassportsandnotmembersofyourfamily"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YouhavebeeninAustraliaandheldyourprovisionalvisaintheInvestorstreamforatleasttwoofthefouryearsimmediatelybeforeyouapply">You have been in Australia and held your provisional visa in the Investor stream for at least two of the four years immediately before you apply::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YouhavebeeninAustraliaandheldyourprovisionalvisaintheInvestorstreamforatleasttwoofthefouryearsimmediatelybeforeyouapply"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YouoryouandyourpartnercombinedhaveheldadesignatedinvestmentwithanAustralianstateorterritoryforatleastfouryears">You (or you and your partner combined) have held a designated investment with an Australian state or territory for at least four years::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YouoryouandyourpartnercombinedhaveheldadesignatedinvestmentwithanAustralianstateorterritoryforatleastfouryears"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Haveyouheldaprovisionalvisasubclass188intheSignificantInvestorstreamorintheSignificantInvestorExtensionstream">Have you held a provisional visa (subclass 188) in the Significant Investor stream or in the Significant Investor Extension stream?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Haveyouheldaprovisionalvisasubclass188intheSignificantInvestorstreamorintheSignificantInvestorExtensionstream"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-HaveyoubeeninAustraliaforatleast40daysperyearcalculatedcumulativelyfortheperiodoftimeyouhaveheldyourprovisionalvisaoryourspousehasbeeninAustraliaforatleast180daysperyearcalculatedcumulativelyfortheperiodoftimetheprimaryapplicanthasheldtheirprovisionalvisas">Have you been in Australia for at least 40 days per year (calculated cumulatively) for the period of time you have held your provisional visa, or your spouse has been in Australia for at least 180 days per year (calculated cumulatively) for the period of time the primary applicant has held their provisional visa(s)::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-HaveyoubeeninAustraliaforatleast40daysperyearcalculatedcumulativelyfortheperiodoftimeyouhaveheldyourprovisionalvisaoryourspousehasbeeninAustraliaforatleast180daysperyearcalculatedcumulativelyfortheperiodoftimetheprimaryapplicanthasheldtheirprovisionalvisas"><p>I do not know and need to discuss before I can answer</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Youoryouandyourpartnercombinedmusthave">You or you and your partner combined must have::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Youoryouandyourpartnercombinedmusthave"><p>C.     I do not know and need to discuss before I can answer.</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Youhaveheldyourprovisionalvisaforaminimumof1year">You have held your provisional visa for a minimum of 1 year::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Youhaveheldyourprovisionalvisaforaminimumof1year"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Youoryouandyourpartnercombinedheldcomplyingpremiuminvestmentscontinuouslyforatleast1yearandfortheentiretimeyouhaveheldyourBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188">You (or you and your partner combined) held complying premium investments continuously for at least 1 year, and for the entire time you have held your Business Innovation and Investment (Provisional) visa (subclass 188)::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Youoryouandyourpartnercombinedheldcomplyingpremiuminvestmentscontinuouslyforatleast1yearandfortheentiretimeyouhaveheldyourBusinessInnovationandInvestmentProvisionalvisasubclass188"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YouhavebeeninAustraliaandheldyourprovisionalEntrepreneurvisaforatleasttwoofthefouryearsandyoucanshowasuccessfulrecordofentrepreneurialactivitiesinAustralia">You have been in Australia and held your provisional Entrepreneur visa for at least two of the four years and you can show a successful record of entrepreneurial activities in Australia::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YouhavebeeninAustraliaandheldyourprovisionalEntrepreneurvisaforatleasttwoofthefouryearsandyoucanshowasuccessfulrecordofentrepreneurialactivitiesinAustralia"><p>No</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Canyoushowthecompletionoftwokeysuccessfactorsoracombinationofonekeysuccessfactorandthreesupportingsuccessfactorsstatedabove">Can you show the completion of two key success factors or a combination of one key success factor and three supporting success factors stated above?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Canyoushowthecompletionoftwokeysuccessfactorsoracombinationofonekeysuccessfactorandthreesupportingsuccessfactorsstatedabove"><p>Yes</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Yourfeedbackisimportantpleasetellushowyoufoundus">Your feedback is important, please tell us how you found us::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Yourfeedbackisimportantpleasetellushowyoufoundus"><p>Facebook</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-QuestionsandCommentscanbewrittenhere">Questions and Comments can be written here::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-QuestionsandCommentscanbewrittenhere"><p>none</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Toreceiveacopyofyourcompletedquestionnaireandensurewedeliveryourinformationtothecorrectinboxpleaseverifyenteryoure-mailaddress">To receive a copy of your completed questionnaire and ensure we deliver your information to the correct inbox please verify (enter) your e-mail address::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Toreceiveacopyofyourcompletedquestionnaireandensurewedeliveryourinformationtothecorrectinboxpleaseverifyenteryoure-mailaddress"><p><a href="mailto:amarkmc@gmail.com">amarkmc@gmail.com</a></p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-TheinformationandresponsesprovidedbymeinthisassessmentquestionnairearetruecorrectandverifiableandIhavereadandaccepttheTermsandConditionsDisclaimerPrivacyPolicyandPrivacyStatement">The information and responses provided by me in this assessment questionnaire are true, correct, and verifiable and I have read and accept the Terms and Conditions , Disclaimer, Privacy Policy and Privacy Statement.:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-TheinformationandresponsesprovidedbymeinthisassessmentquestionnairearetruecorrectandverifiableandIhavereadandaccepttheTermsandConditionsDisclaimerPrivacyPolicyandPrivacyStatement"><p>I Accept (To submit your questionnaire and proceed you must accept)</p>
</dd>
    </dl>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>950.00</span>                      </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            Product - Amarnath&nbsp;                             <strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>                          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-MyName">My Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-MyName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Phone">Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Phone"><p>9382726877</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-File">File:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-File"><ul>
<li><a href="https://www.licensedagents.com.au/wordpress/index.php?gf-download=2018%2F03%2Ftest21.docx&amp;form-id=23&amp;field-id=3&amp;hash=30caf7d7806748e5957bdc185f5d32ee9b90968852374a3152af5bd71c48f582" target="_blank" title="Click to view">test21.docx</a></li>
</ul>
</dd>
    </dl>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>25.00</span>                       </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            Product - Amarnath&nbsp;                             <strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>                          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-MyName">My Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-MyName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Phone">Phone:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Phone"><p>9382726877</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-File">File:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-File"><ul>
<li><a href="https://www.licensedagents.com.au/wordpress/index.php?gf-download=2018%2F03%2Ftest12.docx&amp;form-id=23&amp;field-id=3&amp;hash=5c07cfc190e617a7d2a3549385ab1d0892ef5430de717c1223f0a027aa04ebde" target="_blank" title="Click to view">test12.docx</a></li>
</ul>
</dd>
    </dl>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>25.00</span>                       </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            187 - Regional Sponsored Migration Scheme&nbsp;                          <strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>                          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-Pleaseselectone">Please select one::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Pleaseselectone"><p>I am an employer wanting a potential employee assessed for entry under  the RSMS  (187)</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-FamilyName">Family Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-FamilyName"><p>jaganathan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-GivenName">Given Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-GivenName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Address">Address::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Address"><p>Fl.No#13, Raja Apartments, 5/15 Balakris<br>Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600033<br>India<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Fl.No%2313%2C+Raja+Apartments%2C+5%2F15+Balakris+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600033+India" target="_blank" class="map-it-link">Map It</a></p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Phone">Phone::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Phone"><p>+919382726877</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Email">Email::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Email"><p><a href="mailto:amarkmc@gmail.com">amarkmc@gmail.com</a></p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-NominatedPositionEgElectricalEngineer">Nominated Position (E.g. Electrical Engineer)::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-NominatedPositionEgElectricalEngineer"><p>amarnath jaganathan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-FamilyName">Family Name::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-FamilyName"><p>jaganathan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-GivenName">Given Name::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-GivenName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Address">Address::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Address"><p>Fl.No#13, Raja Apartments, 5/15 Balakris<br>Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600033<br>India<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Fl.No%2313%2C+Raja+Apartments%2C+5%2F15+Balakris+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600033+India" target="_blank" class="map-it-link">Map It</a></p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Phone">Phone::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Phone"><p>+919382726877</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-Email">Email:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Email"><p><a href="mailto:amarkmc@gmail.com">amarkmc@gmail.com</a></p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-DateofBirth">Date of Birth::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-DateofBirth"><p>14/03/2018</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YourCurrentcountryofresidence">Your Current country of residence?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YourCurrentcountryofresidence"><p>Afghanistan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YourPartnersCurrentcountryofresidence">Your Partner's Current country of residence?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YourPartnersCurrentcountryofresidence"><p>Afghanistan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YourCitizenshipasshownonpassport">Your Citizenship as shown on passport?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YourCitizenshipasshownonpassport"><p>Afghanistan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-YourPartnersCitizenshipasshownonpassport">Your Partner's Citizenship as shown on passport?:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-YourPartnersCitizenshipasshownonpassport"><p>Afghanistan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-TellusaboutyourEnglishLanguagecompetencyselectformthedropdownmenu">Tell us about your English Language competency, select form the dropdown menu::</dt>

    </dl>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>350.00</span>                      </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            187 - Regional Sponsored Migration Scheme&nbsp;                          <strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>                          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-Pleaseselectone">Please select one::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-Pleaseselectone"><p>I am an employer wanting a potential employee assessed for entry under  the RSMS  (187)</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-BusinessorCompanyName">Business or Company Name::</dt>
        <dd class="variation-BusinessorCompanyName"><p>A</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-FamilyName">Family Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-FamilyName"><p>jaganathan</p>
</dd>
            <dt class="variation-GivenName">Given Name:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-GivenName"><p>amarnath</p>
</dd>
    </dl>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>350.00</span>                      </td>
                    </tr>
                        </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>2,050.00</span></td>
        </tr>




            <tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <td data-title="Shipping">
                    Free Shipping <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method">     

            </td>
</tr>






        <tr class="order-total">
            <th>Total</th>
            <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>2,050.00</span></strong> </td>
        </tr>


    </tfoot>
</table>

<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">
            <ul class="wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods">
            <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_bacs">
    <input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">

    <label for="payment_method_bacs">
        Direct bank transfer    </label>
            <div class="payment_box payment_method_bacs">
            <p>Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won’t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" data-order_button_text="Proceed to PayPal">

    <label for="payment_method_paypal">
        PayPal <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_AU/mktg/logo/Solutions-graphics-1-184x80.jpg" alt="PayPal acceptance mark"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" class="about_paypal" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;">What is PayPal?</a>   </label>
            <div class="payment_box payment_method_paypal" style="display:none;">
            <p>Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="form-row place-order">
        <noscript>
            Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the &amp;lt;em&amp;gt;Update Totals&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt; button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.          &lt;br/&gt;&lt;button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Update totals"&gt;Update totals&lt;/button&gt;
        </noscript>



        <button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

        <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="cc2ff68013"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/?wc-ajax=update_order_review">   </div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do u have a fiddle or site ?

Comment: @Anuresh https://www.licensedagents.com.au/product/product-amarnath/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Anuresh https://www.licensedagents.com.au/product/189-skilled-migration-scheme/ this could be a better one as due to long fields. When you add this to your cart and checkout, you get to see those all fields below the product title. I want to show only the product-name field and total. And hide all the variations/list under the product name.

Comment: First i need to fill these forms https://prnt.sc/itmj7z ? then only it will add to cart ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/itmlq8 @Anuresh does this help?

Comment: u want like this https://prnt.sc/itmls2 ?

Comment: !!! exactly @Anuresh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this in your style

```
.page-id-8 dl.variation {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes Perfect, worked like a charm. I was meaningless and pondering with the following 
`#order_review >.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table>tbody .cart-item>.product-name >.variation {
    display: none !important;
}` and completely ignored your page id perspective. Thanks a million :)